# Matching Roslyn SourceMemberMethodSymbol with a 'RetargetingMethodSymbol'

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I've been putting some 'find references' code together using Roslyn to search for all method declarations that match a particular signature, and then locate all uses of those methods elsewhere.

It's working in 99% of cases, but I've got an issue where an `InvocationExpressionSyntax.Symbol` is an instance of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Symbols.Retargeting.RetargetingMethodSymbol` instead of a regular `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Symbols.SourceMemberMethodSymbol`. As a consequence this particular call to a target method isn't found (using `ISymbol.Equals`, which uses reference equality). `RetargetingMethodSymbol` has an `UnderlyingMethod` property whose value is the target method I'd expect, but this type is internal and that property isn't exposed.

What is a `RetargetingMethodSymbol`, and how can I see if it corresponds to a `MethodBlockSyntax.Symbol`?

Answer (score 0):

## What is a `RetargetingMethodSymbol`?

Consider a method `M(object o)` that is defined in project `A`, which targets .NET 2.0.

Project `B` targets .NET 4.0, and has a reference to `A`.  In the context of project `B`, `M` will be wrapped in a `RetargetingMethodSymbol`, since the `object` that it refers to in this context isn't the same one that it refers to in the context of `A`.

## How can I see if it corresponds to a `MethodBlockSyntax.Symbol`?

I don't know what you mean by `MethodBlockSyntax.Symbol`, but the VS IDE code uses `SymbolFinder.FindSourceDefinitionAsync()` to find the "original" symbol in cases like this (and also if `A` was written in C# and `B` in VB or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think it's retargeting between .net versions. This is between a small number of assemblies, all .net 4.5 - and all the other calls that work are within these assemblies.

Comment: There are various other cases that can trigger retargeting symbols to get created.  (I don't know all of them :), but the general idea is still the same.